# Asterisk 13 & Pocketsphinx Segmentation Fault

Tags: asterisk, segmentation-fault, sphinx

I've built a voice recognition system for german digits using asterisk 13, pocketsphinx and a plugin and server (based on astsphinx) to connect asterisk with pocketsphinx. When testing the system with calls where wav files are played to the recognition engine everything works fine until about the 50th call. Asterisk then crashes with a segmentation fault and restarts. Reading the gdb backtrace I've found out that the problem occurs, when the format codec id is selected.

This is the gdb backtrace:

```
> [New process 21378]
> #0  0x08155419 in ast_format_get_codec_id (format=0xb6d0cae0) at format.c:319 319 format.c: No such file or directory.    in format.c
> (gdb) bt
> #0  0x08155419 in ast_format_get_codec_id (format=0xb6d0cae0) at format.c:319
> #1  0x081592ad in ast_format_cap_get_compatible (cap1=0xb506b188, cap2=0x8b2c110, result=0x8b3a908) at format_cap.c:591
> #2  0xb6e026a8 in ast_speech_new (engine_name=0xb4ed0fa8 "Sphinx-En", cap=0x8b2c110) at res_speech.c:198
> #3  0xb61fcf2f in speech_create (chan=0x8b279c0, data=0xb4ed0fa8 "Sphinx-En") at app_speech_utils.c:551
> #4  0x081bec23 in pbx_exec (c=0x8b279c0, app=0xb59ad958, data=0xb4ed0fa8 "Sphinx-En") at pbx_app.c:494
> #5  0x081b6973 in pbx_extension_helper (c=0x8b279c0, con=0x0, context=0x8b28048 "/25", exten=0x8b28098 "3000", priority=3,
> label=0x0, 
>     callerid=0xb4d045c0 "25", action=E_SPAWN, found=0xb4ed3348, combined_find_spawn=1) at pbx.c:2886
> #6  0x081bba90 in __ast_pbx_run (c=0x8b279c0, args=0x0) at pbx.c:4111
> #7  0x081bd580 in pbx_thread (data=0x8b279c0) at pbx.c:4610
> #8  0x08234c1b in dummy_start (data=0x8b27480) at utils.c:1239
> #9  0xb7245e6c in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
> #10 0x08b27480 in ?? ()
> #11 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Any Ideas what might cause this?

(Answering Burgis request for the call:) This is the call within the dialplan:

```
exten => 3000,1,Answer()
exten => 3000,n,Set(SPEECH_DTMF_MAXLEN=1)
exten => 3000,n,SpeechCreate(Sphinx-En)
exten => 3000,n,SpeechActivateGrammar(digits.gram)
exten => 3000,n,SpeechStart()
exten => 3000,n(repeat),SpeechBackground(beep,10)
exten => 3000,n,Log(NOTICE,">>>>>>>>>>>RESULT")
exten => 3000,n,Log(NOTICE,${SPEECH_TEXT(0)})
exten => 3000,n,Wait(2)
exten => 3000,n,Goto(repeat)
```

Comment: I think this is probably off-topic for us but might be fit [so]. However they would need to see the code that you are using to diagnose the fault.

Comment: Stack Overflow sent me here because of the use of asterisk.....

Comment: OK can you you share your code then? Specifically the part that makes this call.

Comment: Hello Burgi, added the code segment

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we found the Solution: The Segmentation fault was caused by a bug within asterisks own res_speech module: there is a bug ( matt-jordan committed on 21 Jul 2014, media formats: re-architect handling of media for performance improve…) in res_speech.c.

In the function:

```
struct ast_speech *ast_speech_new(const char *engine_name, const struct ast_format_cap *cap):

    RAII_VAR(struct ast_format *, best, NULL, ao2_cleanup);
```

the variable definition is not correct, because **best** will not be allocated here. **best** only points to **ast_format_slin**.
If the function returns, **ao2_cleanup** decrements the reference from **ast_format_slin** and this does not work.

Replace:

`RAII_VAR(struct ast_format *, best, NULL, ao2_cleanup);`

with:

`struct ast_format *best=NULL;`

and no crash happens (after ~45 calls of the speech-api).